# VSCode does not run modified file in debug

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a javascript project and debug is working, I do stop at the breakpoints. This must be a setting but I cannot for the life of me figure it out, I change code in a file and in the tab that I have open in VSCode it is marked with M next to the file name. As soon as I reach the breakpoint in debug it opens the un-modified file. This is of no use?

Is this something to do with git? All I want to do is run my project and test my changes in debug.

Comment: Hmm, try setting `Debug: Save Before Start` to `none` .  See if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be docker-related.... once I re-build the docker image i was able so see the changes to my files.

I see now that my question did not indicate that I was debugging in a container, my bad.